# where is DIR defined?

Tags: linux, unix

I have just started reading Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment. The first example is for an ls implementation, the code is below. The only thing I don't understand is where is DIR defined. I looked in apue.h (not there) and in dirent.h (not there). Could anyone please tell me where it is defined?

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
DIR             *dp;
struct dirent   *dirp;

if (argc != 2)
    err_quit("usage: ls directory_name");

if ((dp = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
    err_sys("can't open %s", argv[1]);
while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);

closedir(dp);
exit(0);
```

Comment: what platform are you on? on linux, it's in dirent.h: `typedef struct __dirstream DIR`. you can run `grep DIR /usr/include/*.h /usr/include/*/*.h | grep typedef` to find out by yourself.

Comment: thanks for the response. it was in apr_portable.h on my system

Comment: @isedev: More simply: `grep -r 'typedef.*DIR' /usr/include`, or `find /usr/include -type f -name '*.h' | xargs grep 'typedef.*DIR'`

Comment: @KeithThompson thx... `grep -r` I always forget about.

Answer (score 1):

`DIR` is an [opaque data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type), and you should treat it like one, which means when you just want to use it, do not peek in its definition.

This `DIR` comes with `opendir()`, if you want to know how to use them, just run `man opendir` on your terminal, the manual of `opendir()` will tell you

1. which header file(s) you need to include
2. what is the prototype of that function
3. how to handle the return value of that function

and much more.